# Convert comma separated string into array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a comma separated string, which consists of a list of tags and want to convert it to array to get a link for every tag.

Example:

```
$string = 'html,css,php,mysql,javascript';
```

I want to make it like this:

```
<a href="tag/html">html</a>, <a href="tag/css">css</a>, <a href="tag/php">php</a>, <a href="tag/mysql">mysql</a>, <a href="tag/javascript">javascript</a>
```

So the result will be a string containing comma separated links with a space after each link and with no comma after the last link.

I have this function where $arg = 'html,css,php,mysql,javascript':

```
function info_get_tags( $arg ) {
    global $u;

    $tagss = '';
    if ( $arg == '' ) {
        return '';
    } else {
        $tags_arr = explode( ',' , $arg );
        foreach ( $tags_arr as $tag ) {
            $tags = '<a href="' . $u . 'tag/' . $tag . '/" title="' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
            $tagss .= $tags;
        }

        return $tagss;
    }
}
```

This script works for me but without commas and spaces and if we add a comma and a space here:

```
$tags = '<a href="' . $u . 'tag/' . $tag . '/">' . $tag . '</a>, ';
```

we get commas and spaces but there will be a trailing comma after the last link.

Answer (score 17):

Just like you `explode`d you can [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) again:

```
$tags = explode(',', $arg);
foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
    $tag = '<a href="' . $u . 'tag/' . $tag . '/" title="' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
}

return implode(', ', $tags);
```

Comment: this works well for me but would you tell me what's the & before $tag for?

Comment: @med: The `&` means that you iterate by reference. That way you can modify `$tag` and the element in the `$tags` array will be modified, too.

Comment: It's an operator to pass by reference, which means it's directly modifying the original value and not a copy of it.

Comment: You should **always** `unset` the var you have just references within a `foreach`: `foreach ( $a as &$b ) { ... unset($b); }` It's somewher on PHP.net and a very good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that uses array_map instead of the foreach loop:

```
global $u; 
function add_html($tag){
    return('<a href="' . $u . 'tag/' . $tag . '/" title="' . $tag . '">' . $tag .  '</a>');
}
function get_tags($taglist){
    $tags_arr = array_map("add_html", explode( ',' , $taglist));
    return implode(", " , $tags_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this short code

> $string = 'html,css,php,mysql,javascript';
>
> $string = explode(',', $string);
>    foreach( $string as $link){
>    echo `'<a href="tag/'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>';`
> }

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to the html into an array (each tag link is an array element) and then implode on `,`...

```
if ( $arg == '' ) {

    return '';

} else {

    $tags_arr = explode( ',' , $arg );
    $tags  = array();
    $tagtpl = '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>';

    foreach ( $tags_arr as $tag ) {
        $url = $u . 'tag/' . $tag . '/';
        $tags[] = sprintf($tagtpl, $url, $tag, $tag);

    }

    return implode(', ', $tags);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$tagss = trim($tagss);    
return substr($tagss, 0 , strlen($tagss)-1);
```

Comment: You can just write `substr($tagss, 0, -2)` ;)

Comment: @nikic yeap you're right, faster and nicer, but rtrim is even better

Answer (score 0):

Why not put all tags in an array when you are creating them, and later explode the array and add the commas and spaces between the tags.

```
foreach ( $tags_arr as $tag ) {
    $tags = '<a href="' . $u . 'tag/' . $tag . '/" title="' . $tag . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
    $tagss[] = $tags;
}
$tagss = explode(', ', $tagss);
```

Answer (score 0):

The *workaround*(!) would be to remove the unwanted trailing characters afterwards:

```
$tagss = rtrim($tagss, ", ");
```

This [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) removes any mix of spaces and commas from the right end of the string.

Btw, you could use [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) instead of explode, which also handles input spaces better.

Answer (score 0):

```
function info_get_tags($arg)
{
    global $u;
    if (empty($arg)) return '';
    return ltrim(preg_replace('/([^\,]+)/', ' <a href="' . $u . '/${1}/" title="${1}">${1}</a>', $arg));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'html,css,php,mysql,javascript';

puts $string.split(/,/).map { |tag| "<a href=\"tag/#{tag}\">#{tag}</a>"}.join(", ")
```

result:

```
<a href="tag/html">html</a>, <a href="tag/css">css</a>, <a href="tag/php">php</a>, <a href="tag/mysql">mysql</a>, <a href="tag/javascript">javascript</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

Another solution:

```
$html = trim(preg_replace('/([^,]+)/', ' <a href="/tags/\1" title="\1">\1</a>', $string));
```

Or if you have to html encode the tags (always smart, since you're creating html from text):

```
$html = trim(preg_replace_callback('/([^,]+)/', function($match) {
    $tag = $match[1];
    return ' <a href="/tags/' . urlencode($tag) . '" title="' . htmlspecialchars($tag) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($tag) . '</a>';
}, $string));
```

So this `$string` would work too: `"tag with space,html,css,php,mysql,javascript"`

More regex is always good!