# Send array by volley android to php

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to write a small code that send array from my android application by volley android to php file a that will write the array in text file here is my array

```
>String[] title = {
                    "Abundance",
                    "Anxiety",
                    "Bruxism",
                    "Discipline",
                    "Drug Addiction"
            };
```

my volley code:

```
>UploadRequest registerRequest = new UploadRequest(title, responseListener);
            RequestQueue volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            DiskBasedCache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 64 * 2048 * 2048);
            volleyQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));
            volleyQueue.start();
            volleyQueue.add(registerRequest);
```

---

*my stringRequest class UploadRequest.java*

```
public class UploadRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL ="http://192.168.2.115/app/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public UploadRequest(String[] names, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    
    params.put("names", String.valueOf(names));//i think my problem is here!

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

*my Register.php file*

> $value = $_POST['names'];
>
> $fp = fopen('Log.txt', 'w');
>
> fwrite($fp, $value);
>
> fclose($fp);

*the output of the php file in the text file 'Log.txt' that came from the array*

> [Ljava.lang.String;@41c509a8

So my problem the array comes wrong or I didnt declare the array! so please how can I declare it.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send array values , instead of reference hash code so use `Arrays.toString`

```
 params.put("names", Arrays.toString(names));
```

---

```
    String[] title = {
            "Abundance",
            "Anxiety",
            "Bruxism",
            "Discipline",
            "Drug Addiction"
    };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(title));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(title));
```

Output :

```
[Abundance, Anxiety, Bruxism, Discipline, Drug Addiction]
[Ljava.lang.String;@14eac69
```

Option 2.

You can create `JSONARRAY` and put values into `JSONARRAY` and later use `jsonarray.toString()`

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put("Abundance");
    array.put("Anxiety");
    array.put("Bruxism");
    System.out.println(array.toString());
```

output :

```
["Abundance","Anxiety","Bruxism"]
```

Comment: @Steve.r i am glad , that i could help , happy coding  :)

Comment: now I'm trying to fetch this array ["Abundance","Anxiety","Bruxism"] on php by separate line, one by one to insert it into mysql, looks like its hard a little bit.

Comment: @Steve.r read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845121/convert-comma-separated-string-into-array

Comment: for sure i've accept it, thanks again and hope to find php solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
params.put("names", String.valueOf(names));//i think my problem is here!
```

Indeed. Better try something like:

```
params.put("names[0]", names[0]);
params.put("names[1]", names[1]);
params.put("names[2]", names[2]);
.... of course you would make a loop for it
```

Or:

```
params.put("names0", names[0]);
params.put("names1", names[1]);
params.put("names2", names[2]);
......
```

Your php script would be different for the two cases.